# How long will NetworkStream Read wait, before dying?

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-xp, networkstream

I have a call to `Read` on `NetworkStream` objeck, which uses `Socket.Receive` internally.

Say that no data is comming in. How long before the Read Method exits?
`ReceiveTimeout` is set to 0 (infinite timeout).

What if I unplug the internet cable? Will it exit?

Comment: The MTBF for power supplies is around 8 years or so.

Comment: Uptill the first windows update then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you unplug the cabel you will get [IOException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception.aspx).
You'll get this exception if socket is closed on the other end.

You might get an [ObjectDisposedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.objectdisposedexception.aspx) if there is a network problem.
[More info in this MSDN article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx)

Otherwise it might run for around 8 years, as Hans pointed out :)